# How to get option selected values from aspx to in ashx.cs

Tags: asp.net, ashx

i wan to get the selected value from option list and check in ashx.cs page ? how can i achive this task ?
i'm very new to ashx file?

```
  public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{
   HttpPostedFile uploads = context.Request.Files["upload"];
   string CKEditorFuncNum = context.Request["CKEditorFuncNum"];
   string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploads.FileName);
   string DomainName = "http://" +context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + "/";
   var filePath = DomainName + "UrlImageService/Images/" + uploads.FileName;
   string CompletePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + file;
   uploads.SaveAs(CompletePath);
    //uploads.SaveAs(savePath);              
   //provide direct URL here     
   context.Response.Write("<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction("+CKEditorFuncNum + ", \"" + filePath + "\");</script>");
   context.Response.End();    

}
public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
```

and i'm calling my file this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
        // instance, using default configuration.
            CKEDITOR.replace('textEditor', {
            width: '700px',
            height: '300px',
            //filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/uploader/upload.php?type=Files',
            filebrowserUploadUrl: 'Upload.ashx'              
            });               
    });       
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send that check-box value to the server somehow...
so maybe your js function should add that value as a query string this way the context.Request["CKEditorFuncNum"] will not be null.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var checkBoxValue = $("[id$=CKEditorFuncNum]").val();
    // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
    // instance, using default configuration.
        CKEDITOR.replace('textEditor', {
        width: '700px',
        height: '300px',
        //filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/uploader/upload.php?type=Files',
        filebrowserUploadUrl: 'Upload.ashx?CKEditorFuncNum=' + checkBoxValue //here I added the value of the check-box 
        });               
});
```

Comment: var checkBoxValue = $("[cmbCategory$=CKEditorFuncNum]").val(); it give me 1 on every call

Comment: i want to send value on button click , above js function get the value on load  that's on every call i get cmbselected val is 1 ????? how can i  over come on this issue?

Comment: then you should do this logic on click.. 
$($("select yout button here").click(
function () {
    var checkBoxValue = $("[id$=CKEditorFuncNum]").val();
    .....
});